# How do I get the dateTimePicker to not rely on system date format C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, datetimepicker

I have this code that sets the time on the `dateTimePicker` but it crashes on my mates computer because his Windows system date format is dd/MM/yy. I tried to set a custom time in the property field and in code but it doesn't accept it. How do I force the `dateTimePicker` to use a certain format?

```
deadline_dtp.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
deadline_dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
deadline_dtp.Value = new DateTime(idYYYY, idMM, idDD);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must work according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Give it a try by setting the format before the custom format.

*Example*

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        }
```

[image]

*Edit after comment*

Add this 2 lines in the upper method:

```
var rightNow = DateTime.Now;
dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(rightNow.Year, rightNow.Month, rightNow.Day);
```

If that is still not working, try to debug the values that are coming from your arguments in "new Datetime(...".